# How to assign certificate to IMAP/S and SMTP/S in Exchange 2016?

Tags: security, exchange, certificate, imap

Please advise me because I pull all my hair out.

I have Exchange 2016 and I want to assign one officially signed-off certificate to the IMAP/S port 993/tcp and SMTP/S port 465/tcp .
I went through several configuration options but checking the ports (by using `nmap`) both ports presents an absolute different certificate. I don't get the whole concept now of managing Exchange certs.

IMAP Setting on Exchange

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ImapSettings | fl

RunspaceId                        : 669149f3-c8f4-43af-b80c-3019ec26bd08
ProtocolName                      : IMAP4
Name                              : 1
MaxCommandSize                    : 10240
ShowHiddenFoldersEnabled          : False
UnencryptedOrTLSBindings          : {[::]:143, 0.0.0.0:143}
SSLBindings                       : {[::]:993, 0.0.0.0:993}
InternalConnectionSettings        : {mail.doamin.il:143:TLS, mail.domain.il:993:SSL}
ExternalConnectionSettings        : {mail.domain.il:993:SSL, mail.domain.il:143:TLS}
X509CertificateName               : mail.domain.il
Banner                            : The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
LoginType                         : SecureLogin
AuthenticatedConnectionTimeout    : 00:30:00
PreAuthenticatedConnectionTimeout : 00:01:00
MaxConnections                    : 2147483647
MaxConnectionFromSingleIP         : 2147483647
MaxConnectionsPerUser             : 16
MessageRetrievalMimeFormat        : BestBodyFormat
ProxyTargetPort                   : 1993
CalendarItemRetrievalOption       : iCalendar
OwaServerUrl                      :
EnableExactRFC822Size             : False
LiveIdBasicAuthReplacement        : False
SuppressReadReceipt               : False
ProtocolLogEnabled                : False
EnforceCertificateErrors          : False
LogFileLocation                   : C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\Imap4
LogFileRollOverSettings           : Hourly
LogPerFileSizeQuota               : 0 B (0 bytes)
ExtendedProtectionPolicy          : None
EnableGSSAPIAndNTLMAuth           : True
Server                            : SERVER
AdminDisplayName                  :
ExchangeVersion                   : 0.10 (14.0.100.0)
DistinguishedName                 : CN=1,CN=IMAP4,CN=Protocols,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBO
                                    HF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=SERVERADS,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configu
                                    ration, DC=domain,DC=ils
Identity                          : SERVER\1
Guid                              : c2bfe9aa-f252-419a-910d-62687592dc34
ObjectCategory                    : domain.ils/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Protocol-Cfg-IMAP-Server
ObjectClass                       : {top, protocolCfg, protocolCfgIMAP, protocolCfgIMAPServer}
WhenChanged                       : 2024. 01. 23. 20:56:48
WhenCreated                       : 2021. 04. 29. 16:12:26
WhenChangedUTC                    : 2024. 01. 23. 19:56:48
WhenCreatedUTC                    : 2021. 04. 29. 14:12:26
OrganizationId                    :
Id                                : SERVER\1
OriginatingServer                 : DC.domain.ils
IsValid                           : True
ObjectState                       : Unchanged
```

The result of `nmap`.

```
[root@revenant ~]# nmap -p 993 --script ssl-cert mail.domain.il
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-01-23 22:09 CET
Nmap scan report for mail.domain.il (192.168.99.31)
Host is up (0.00027s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
993/tcp open  imaps
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=*.domain.il/organizationName=IL Inc./stateOrProvinceName=F/countryName=IL
| Subject Alternative Name: DNS:*.domain.il
| Issuer: commonName=internal-ca/organizationName=IL Inc./stateOrProvinceName=F/countryName=IL
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
| Not valid before: 2023-06-15T20:20:44
| Not valid after:  2028-06-13T20:20:44
| MD5:   ffc2 d46a f66e b7ee 8f2c 0468 4f39 f01e
|_SHA-1: 626d bfac d38c db8f 5ea9 d328 c42c d94a d9fe 09c1
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:0D:B3:C3 (VMware)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.47 seconds
```

Clarifying I have two certificates. mail.domain.il is signed-off by Truster Root Issuer and *.domain.il is signed off by my Internal CA.

Exchange OWA is configured with mail.domain.il in IIS and it works well but EXCHANGE services do not want to pick it up or I don't know how the services decide they operate.

`Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Server SERVER -Thumbprint 1KJ24JH12G41JKG41J23H4G12JKL3G -Services IIS,SMTP,POP,IMAP` was used several times. I tried really everything but I cannot make it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign certificates to services in the Exchange admin center (EAC) or in the Exchange Management Shell. Once you assign a certificate to a service, you can’t remove the assignment. If you no longer want to use a certificate for a specific service, you need to assign another certificate to the service, and then remove the certificate that you don’t want to use.

It’s important to note that you should not assign a wildcard certificate to the IMAP4 or POP3 service. Instead, use the Set-ImapSettings cmdlet to configure the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) that clients use to connect to the IMAP4 service, and use the Set-PopSettings cmdlet to configure the FQDN that clients use to connect to the POP3 service.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. This is the theory. But in praxis it means that I had to assign the new certificate to the services. MUST remove the "self-signed" certificate (even it is used by another service/website). Exchange picked up the "good" one. After I had to reassign the "self-signed" again to another service/website. (I'm gonna add the solution soon.)